OpenAI API in NextJS not giving a response
I'm followed a tutorial to T but unable to get a response from the API. I'm not sure if there was an update to OpenAI API or not.
Any help will be much appreciated.
Error
http://localhost:3000/api/chat-gpt net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)
onClick @   page.tsx:13
Show 14 more frames

/app/(main)/page.tsx
'use client'
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './_components/navbar';

const HomePage = () => {
  return ( 
    <div className="w-full min-h-full">
      <Navbar />
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center">
        <h1 className="text-4xl">Welcome to Mood Palette</h1>
        <button
          onClick={async () => {
            const response = await fetch('/api/chat-gpt', {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'Hello, World!',
              }),
            });
            console.log("Response", response);
          }}
        >
          Create Palette
        </button>
      </div>

    </div>
   );
}
 
export default HomePage;


/app/api/route.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import OpenAI from "openai";

const openai = new OpenAI({
    apiKey: `Bearer ${process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY}`,
    project: 'project_id',
});

export async function POST(request: Request) {


    const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({ 
        model: "gpt-3.5-turbo", 
        messages: [
            { role: "system", content: "You are Jarvis from Iron Manl" },
            { role: "user", content: "Who are you?"}
        ],
        temperature: 0,
        max_tokens: 1024,
        top_p: 1,
        frequency_penalty: 0,
        presence_penalty: 0
    });

    return NextResponse.json(response);
}

I just followed a the Open AI doc's 'getting started' and a tutorial but unable to progress after the API is not responding.

Based on your details it seems that you are pointing to an endpoint that doesnt exist:
your api file should be under:
/app/api/chat-gpt/route.ts

Thanks, I tried doing that but the error is there still. At this point I might just use Flask as it works seamlessly there.

whats the error?
